# Tips/help to debug no apk file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My environment :

- Eclipse sdk 3.7.2
- Worklight pluin 5.0.5
- Android sdk 2.2

First I tried a simple Hello World, everything works fine, android native project was created and I see  the corresponding apk file was generated after a build and deploy.

Next I  imported a sample project, successfully got it run on the test (localhost) server, able to see the expected result on the android Mobile Browser Simulator but the problem now is I am not seeing the corresponding android apk file got generated (the android native project was created).  No errors on the logs,   Any idea what could be the problem?  How one debug such a problem.

Answer (score 3):

APK will be generated under \bin\ folder once you run your app for the first time.
Connect your Android device to dev machine via USB cable (assuming you got Android SDK etc installed), right click on Android project and do Run as->Android app.

The app will be installed and started on Android device. APK will be generated in \bin folder.

In general, you don't need the device, same thing can be done with emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do an export on the android application project. This is what you would do if you are looking at doing some key signing. This is the way you would want to export it if you are uploading to Google play or an enterprise app store.

Keep in mind, Worklight doesn't build your .ipa, .apk, or etc. It builds you compile ready resources. It will build you the folder structure and the project layers needed to build in the corresponding Native Environment (for apple, you would export to xcode, build it, and run).